# Need to get data with BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, tags

I'm fine with this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url ="https://www.cosmoprof.com/en/visit/exhibitors-directory/exhibitors-list/?y=0&page=1"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all("div", class_="col-md-3 result-item mb-40")

for result in results:
    company = result.find("h3")
    country = result.find("li")
    

    print(f"company:{company.get_text()}")
    print(f"country:{country.get_text()}")
```

company:LABORATOIRE REVITACARE
country: COUNTRY/REGION: France
company:LONDONTOWN INC.
country: COUNTRY/REGION: USA

//
But when I try to get more data, like Sector: = Beauty or Hall = 29 I'm stuck :-(

```
`<div class="col-md-3 result-item mb-40">
<span class="tag-new">new 2023</span>
<h3>LABORATOIRE REVITACARE</h3>
<ul class="lista-dati-espositore" style="min-height:110px;">
<li><span> COUNTRY/REGION:</span> France</li>
<li style="min-height:50px;"><span> Sector:</span> Beauty &amp; Spa</li>
<li><span> Hall:</span> 29</li>
<li>
<span> Stand No.:</span>
                                                                E/12
                                                         </li>
<li><span> Opening dates:</span> From 17 to 20 March 2023</li>
</ul>
<a href="/en/visit/exhibitors-directory/exhibitors-list/exhibitor-details/?id=22838&amp;s=laboratoire-revitacare" title="LABORATOIRE REVITACARE"> Find out more</a>
`
```

Any one?

I can't find the right code to get other data out of

tags

Answer (score 0):

To get all data into a pandas DataFrame you can use next example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.cosmoprof.com/en/visit/exhibitors-directory/exhibitors-list/?y=0&page=1"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

items = []
for item in soup.select(".bible-page-results .row > div"):
    items.append(
        {
            "Title": item.h3.text,
            **{li.span.text.strip(':'): li.span.find_next_sibling(text=True).strip() for li in item.select("li")},
        }
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(items)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                           Title  COUNTRY/REGION                                      Sector  Hall          Stand No.             Opening dates
0                         LABORATOIRE REVITACARE          France                                Beauty & Spa    29               E/12  From 17 to 20 March 2023
1                                LONDONTOWN INC.             USA                      Cosmetics & Toiletries    19          E/1 - F/2  From 16 to 18 March 2023
2               3 CLAVELES - BUENO HERMANOS S.A.           Spain  Furnishing and equipment for professionals    33               G/20  From 17 to 20 March 2023
3                            3G PACKAGING S.R.L.           Italy                                   Cosmopack    20               B/36  From 16 to 18 March 2023
4                                    4 STARLINGS          Poland                             Green & Organic    21                O/6  From 16 to 18 March 2023
5                                     4MASS S.A.          Poland                      Cosmetics & Toiletries    16               H/3e  From 16 to 18 March 2023
6                                          66°30          France          Extraordinary Gallery - Cosmoprime  14EG                 39  From 16 to 18 March 2023
7                                          7DAYS           Italy                      Cosmetics & Toiletries    22        B/29 - C/30  From 16 to 18 March 2023
8               A&H INTERNATIONAL COSMETICS INC.           China                      Cosmetics & Toiletries    16             N/4-N6  From 16 to 18 March 2023
9   A. YAMA COSMETICS - FROM BRAZIL TO THE WORLD          Brazil                           Professional Hair    37  A/3 - A/4 - B/13B  From 17 to 20 March 2023
10                                 A.P.S. S.R.L.           Italy                                   Cosmopack    20               D/32  From 16 to 18 March 2023
11                         AAKON POLICHIMICA SRL           Italy                                   Cosmopack    20               A/44  From 16 to 18 March 2023
12                                   ABACOSM LTD          Greece                                Beauty & Spa    29               C/30  From 17 to 20 March 2023
13                         ABC INTERNATIONAL LTD          U.A.E.                      Cosmetics & Toiletries    26              A/101  From 16 to 18 March 2023
14                abc nailstore - Nails & Lashes           Italy                                   Nailworld    36        A/12 - B/11  From 17 to 20 March 2023
15                                   ABC TEXTURE          France                                   Cosmopack   15A     A/2 - B/1 - C/  From 16 to 18 March 2023
16                                         ABOVE          Brazil                      Cosmetics & Toiletries    26               A/71  From 16 to 18 March 2023
17          ABOVE SHEARS/ABOVE INTERNATIONAL USA             USA  Furnishing and equipment for professionals    33               G/32  From 17 to 20 March 2023
18                             ABSOLUTE COLLAGEN  United Kingdom                      Cosmetics & Toiletries    19               G/1b  From 16 to 18 March 2023
19                      ACCADEMIA DELLA BELLEZZA           Italy                                Beauty & Spa    30               A/23  From 17 to 20 March 2023
```